# Postgresql Bad Connection when starting Rails Server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I recently installed Ruby (version: 2.0.0p598) and Rails (version: 4.1.8) on my Windows 8 computer. Everything seemed to work fine when starting up a freshly created app on rails server...

However now I want to create a rails app using postgresql as my database. I created the app with the following line of code. `rails new -T -d postgresql app_name`

When I start up the server and load up the browser I get `PG::ConnectionBad` & `fe_sendauth: no password supplied`

I thought this was caused by postgresql not being installed on my computer so I did so with the [Windows Postgreql installer](http://www.postgresql.org/download/windows/) however when I try `psql --version` in the terminal I get `'psql' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

I thought I already installed postgresql... so why is it not recognizing it?

I've checked my gemfile and `gem 'pg'` is there and I bundled as well.

Also here is my logs

```
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-03-26 21:45:24 -0400

PG::ConnectionBad (fe_sendauth: no password supplied
):
  activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:888:in `initialize'
  activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:888:in `new'
  activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:888:in `connect'
  activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:568:in `initialize'
  activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:41:in `new'
  activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:41:in `postgresql_connection'
  activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:435:in `new_connection'
  activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:445:in `checkout_new_connection'
  activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:416:in `acquire_connection'
  activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:351:in `block in checkout'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
  activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:350:in `checkout'
  activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:265:in `block in connection'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
  activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:264:in `connection'
  activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:541:in `retrieve_connection'
  activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:113:in `retrieve_connection'
  activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:87:in `connection'
  activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:51:in `restore_query_cache_settings'
  activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:43:in `rescue in call'
  activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:32:in `call'
  activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:621:in `call'
  activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/migration.rb:380:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:82:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:26:in `call'

  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:84:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
  railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
  railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'


  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (2.0ms)
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (4.0ms)
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (3.0ms)
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (237.7ms)
```

Comment: Have a look [here](http://wiki.ispirer.com/sqlways/troubleshooting-guide/postgresql/import/psql_exe). Try the first solution if you didn't already.

Comment: Test to see whether PostgreSQL is running. (Windows task manager) Then check to see whether `psql` is in your path.

Comment: So I got PostgreSQL in the PATH and I can now see the current version when I run `psql --version` however I still get the original error on the browser side `PG::ConnectionBad fe_sendauth: no password supplied`. I'm seeing on other SO answers that I should have the password and username in the database.yml but I never had to do such a thing when working with psql on a mac.

Comment: The Rails configuration file database.yml and the psql client program don't have anything to do with each other. If the description in your question is right, at the very least you need to enter the PostgreSQL username and password for the development environment in config/database.yml.